# prevent access to home page for anyone unless has username and password

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have made a project and i have faced some issue about Permissions and Authorization the problem I am facing is anyone can access to any page in my project without login by just copy and past the Url he can access to any page I want to stop that an let only the people who has user name and password get the permission

this is my url.py

```
 `from django.urls import path
  from . import views

   app_name = 'store'

   urlpatterns = [
path('', views.signin, name = "signin"),
path('login', views.index, name="index"),
path('logout', views.signout, name="signout"),
path('registration', views.registration, name="registration"),
path('book/<int:id>', views.get_book, name="book"),
path('books', views.get_books, name="books"),
path('category/<int:id>', views.get_book_category, 
name="category"),
path('writer/<int:id>', views.get_writer, name = "writer"),
  ]`
```

this is my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, 
    get_object_or_404
       from django.contrib.auth.models import User
       from .models import Category, Writer, Book, Review, Slider
       from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
         from django.contrib import messages
         from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, 
    PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
        from .forms import RegistrationForm, ReviewForm
       from django.http import HttpResponse
    def index(request):
    newpublished = Book.objects.order_by('-created')[:15]
    slide = Slider.objects.order_by('-created')[:3]
    context = {
        "newbooks":newpublished,
        "slide": slide
    }
    return render(request, 'store/index.html', context)


 def signin(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('store:index')
else:
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.POST.get('user')
        password = request.POST.get('pass')
         auth = authenticate(request, username=user, 
password=password)
        if auth is not None:
            login(request, auth)
            return redirect('store:index')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'username and password 
doesn\'t match')

return render(request, "store/login.html")  


def signout(request):
logout(request)
return redirect('store:index')  


def registration(request):
form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('store:signin')

return render(request, 'store/signup.html', {"form": form})

def payment(request):
return render(request, 'store/payment.html')


def get_book(request, id):
form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None)
book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
rbooks = Book.objects.filter(category_id=book.category.id)
r_review = Review.objects.filter(book_id=id).order_by('- 
created')

paginator = Paginator(r_review, 4)
page = request.GET.get('page')
rreview = paginator.get_page(page)

if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if form.is_valid():
            temp = form.save(commit=False)
            temp.customer = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            temp.book = book          
            temp = Book.objects.get(id=id)
            temp.totalreview += 1
            temp.totalrating += 
    int(request.POST.get('review_star'))
            form.save()  
            temp.save()

            messages.success(request, "Review Added 
Successfully")
            form = ReviewForm()
    else:
        messages.error(request, "You need login first.")
context = {
    "book":book,
    "rbooks": rbooks,
    "form": form,
    "rreview": rreview,
    "download_url": book.pdf_file.url,  # Use the 'pdf_file' 
field to get the PDF file URL
      #"download_url": book.url, Include the 'url' field in the 
context
}
return render(request, "store/book.html", context)


def get_books(request):
books_ = Book.objects.all().order_by('-created')
paginator = Paginator(books_, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page')
books = paginator.get_page(page)
return render(request, "store/category.html", {"book":books})

def get_book_category(request, id):
book_ = Book.objects.filter(category_id=id)
paginator = Paginator(book_, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page')
book = paginator.get_page(page)
return render(request, "store/category.html", {"book":book})

def get_writer(request, id):
wrt = get_object_or_404(Writer, id=id)
book = Book.objects.filter(writer_id=wrt.id)
context = {
    "wrt": wrt,
    "book": book
}
return render(request, "store/writer.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page, it describes exactly what you need in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) It makes sure that only authenticated users can access a certain page.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def get_book(request, id):
   etc...
```

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working

Comment: could you show the code including this example, as it should definitely work